# How many slokas are there in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata

How many slokas are there in Gita press Mahabharata ?

Gita press Mahabharata is  Authentic ?

Answer (score 3):

Gita press mahabharat have 100,217 shlokas In which 86600 are from North indian scripts, 6584 from South indian recession and 7033 are उवाच shlokas.[image]

Comment: Where you got this

Comment: Do Gita press told

Comment: Can I get reference

Comment: yes this is screenshot of gitapress book only

Comment: Page number of Gita press book